# Keyboard notifications after modal dialog

Tags: iphone, keyboard, notifications, modalviewcontroller

I have a `UITableViewController` with some rows containing textfields, and other rows that show a modal view. I register for the `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` and `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` in `viewWillAppear`, and unregister in `viewWillDisappear`.

Next I do this:
- click on a textfield. I get the `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification`, resize the table to have place for the keyboard.
- select a row that presents a modal view controller, I receive the `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification`, and `viewWillDisappear` is called.
- after closing the modal view controller, `viewWillAppear` is called, and I get a `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification`. But no keyboard is shown. So my table is resized, but no keyboard appears.

Is this a bug in the SDK? Or is it common behavior and I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Your logic seams correct to me. But I wonder about a possible problem with registering for a `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` every time your `viewWillAppear`. Try to register only once in `viewDidLoad` and unsubscribe in `dealloc`. I am thinking that maybe when you register again after you dismiss the modal view the Notification Center sends you an old notification. If you register once for a notification you will not get it more then it is posted.

Comment: But why would I receive an old UIKeyboardWillShowNotification on a modal dismiss? I already received the correct willShow notification the first time. The second one only makes sense if the keyboard was going to appear.